# Nested associate different models using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, associations

I have association sequelize problem, like this question, but not exactly same,

[Associate different models using sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501856/associate-different-models-using-sequelize)

[How to implement many to many association in sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958683/how-to-implement-many-to-many-association-in-sequelize)

in my model A.js

```
A.associate = function (models) {

    models.B.hasMany(models.A, {
        as: 'aliasA',
        foreignKey: 'ids',
    });

    models.A.hasOne(models.C, {
        as: 'aliasC',
        foreignKey: 'id',
    });
});
```

The first associate is works, the second didn't works,,

Comment: sry, i think this is my fault..

Comment: what's the correct way?