# Sequelize - How to list/view all columns of existing model

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I know a simple answer could be query table with all attributes returned.

However, since the models are defined in code, I want to know is it possible to get the result without querying database? 
Or, if query is necessary, which query is the optimised one?

Btw, I am using **Sequelize V5** and **Mysql 5.7**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can iterate over `rawAttributes` of the Model class

```
for( let key in Model.rawAttributes ){
    console.log('Field Name: ', key); // this is name of the field
    console.log('Field Type: ', Model.rawAttributes[key].type.key); // Sequelize type of field
}
```

The *keys* of `rawAttributes` are the field names aka column names; the *values* of `rawAttributes` are the Sequelize definitions of those columns, including [properties explained in the `init/define` methods.](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-init), such as `type`, `allowNull`, `defaultValue`, `unique`, etc...

Remember to check `rawAttributes` **after** you [create any associations](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/) and any other setup on your `Model` (`Model.hasOne()` or `Model.belongsTo()`, anything in your [`Model.associate()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45505555/1175496)), otherwise the attributes object **won't include foreign key columns**.

Side-note, in Sequelize v4, `Model.attributes===Model.rawAttributes`, so they are aliases for the same thing.

In Sequelize v6+, you can use [`Model.getAttributes()`, which is documented](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-getAttributes)

Comment: Thanks. Is the "rawAttributes" explained in official documents? It will hard to figure it out without documentation.

Comment: yeap, the documentation of sequelize isn´t that good but checking how are the files are generated you can figureout, and with some research

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this as an answer:

```
for( let key of Object.keys(models.Modelname.attributes))   {
      columns.push({
          name:key,
          type:models.Modelname.attributes[key].type.key
      });
}
```

Comment: This would be an expensive operation, re-calculating `Object.keys` in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It seems each model has an attribute "rawAttributes" which include all columns name. This may not be the official way, but it can solve my problem.